# unable to select id mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a query which selects random rows from table and am trying to select id along with another three rows but when I include `id` to be selected it gives me error. if I remove the `id` the query works fine. The reason I need the `id` is because I need it to pass via url to the second page. What am I missing?

```
Call to a member function execute() on a non-object
```

The query:

```
   $stmt = $mydb->prepare("SELECT  id, title, price, image_one
        FROM products AS r1 JOIN
           (SELECT (RAND() *
             (SELECT MAX(id)
         FROM products )) AS id)
        AS r2
 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id and title != ''
 ORDER BY r1.id ASC
 LIMIT 1 ");
 $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing error checking.

Every time you prepare or execute a query, you should check the result.  The function returns **false** if there's an error.

For example, if I try running your query, I get this error:

```
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous
```

There are two `id` columns in this query:  `r1.id` and `r2.id`.  You need to qualify the column so it's unambiguous which one you mean to query.

```
SELECT r1.id, title, ...
```

But more important, **check the result** returned by prepare().

```
$stmt = $mydb->prepare(...);
if ($stmt === false) {
    trigger_error($mydb->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

The same thing applies to execute(), because that can cause execution-time errors:

```
if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
    trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: I already have `if ( false===$stmt ) {
  die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mydb ->error));
}` to check for errors but it doesn't show anything in this case.